# Проблама с подключением файлов в проекст Qt на Windows 7

Tags: qt, mingw

Не могу собрать проект в Qt(5.14.2) на Windows 7 из-за подключения файлов через относительный путь. 
Так как в проекте файлов много - подключаю их следующим образом.

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Src
SOURCES += $$PWD/Src/*.cpp
HEADERS += $$PWD/Src/*.h
```

И получаю следующую ошибку при сборке проекта (MinGW 64-bit). Не работает только на Window 7. На Windows 10 - всё ок.

```
:-1: ошибка: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
```

Но следующим способом подключения файлов - проект собирается. Т.е. нужно прописать каждый файл

```
SOURCES += $$PWD/Src/source1.cpp \
    $$PWD/Src/source2.cpp \
    $$PWD/Src/source3.cpp \
    $$PWD/Src/main.cpp

HEADERS += $$PWD/Src/header1.h \
    $$PWD/Src/header2.h \
    $$PWD/Src/header3.h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

странно что работает.

вот так пропишите

```
SOURCES = $$files(*.cpp, true)
HEADERS = $$files(*.h, true)
```

Comment: Получилось, спасибо.